# How much is the speed of copying by sendfile() in a c++ code on linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I am a beginner and my question is not a homework. I want to write a C++ code in Linux to copy a large (40GiG) binary file.

My code has to meet the following conditions:

- the speed should be the same as copying with the OS
- amount of RAM should be assumed to be 4GiG

Currently, I use:

> sendfile (write_fd, read_fd, &offset, stat_buf.st_size);

Does `sendfile` satisfy the mentioned conditions?

How i can evaluate the speed of copying by a code versus the speed of copying by the OS?

Comment: what do you mean by "copying by OS"? sendfile is actually a OS function! do you mean "faster than any standard command line tool?"

Comment: Yes. I want to have the fastest standard command line tool.

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is that you should try it yourself and run some benchmarks.

However, to give you a hint, I quote the man page for [sendfile()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html):

> Because this copying is done within the kernel, sendfile() is more efficient than the combination of read(2) and write(2), which would require transferring data to and from user space.

This should give you a pretty good idea.

Comment: Thanks, but I before have read it. Unfortunately i do not know how compare the speed of copying of a code with the speed of a OS.

Comment: @Code Use your code to copy a file and measure the time it takes. Then use "the OS" (by which I assume you basically mean using `cp` from a shell) and measure how long that takes. Do this several times to rule out caching effects and compare the times.

Comment: @dvnrs can be 'pv' (http://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/progress-and-speed-with-cp) as a evaluation of the speed of OS?

Comment: @Code just use the `[time](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_time.htm)` command. Or use a stopwatch. Or Google for "how to measure a program's run time" or something.

Comment: I have just `strace`d `cp`, doesn't seem to use `sendfile()` on Ubuntu 16.04. Also confirmed [here](https://jvns.ca/blog/2016/01/23/sendfile-a-new-to-me-system-call/).

Answer (score 2):

`sendfile` is nowadays implemented in terms of `splice`, so directly using `splice` might still be a little faster. Although most probably there will be no noticeable difference in the usual case. You might save a few hundred CPU cycles, but the latency involved reading from a disk (or similar device) is a million times more heavyweight.

In the special case of copying huge amounts of data from/to different devices, using a series of `splice` calls (with two or more pipes) may in some cases be significantly faster than a single `splice` or `sendfile`, since this would allow you overlap writes with reads.

You could splice a certain amount of data (say 1MB) from one disk into a pipe, and then splice from the pipe to the other device. Meanwhile, you can splice the next block of data into another pipe. That way, both devices will read and write asynchronously rather than lockstep.

Since physical *disk* writes are realized lazily, the OS will automatically do this kind of optimization when copying data to a *disk drive*, and the difference will usually be zero in that case.

However, when copying to other types of devices (say, destination is e.g. a socket), this will make a huge difference, or if you need to make sure that certain ranges of data have successfully been written in between (which means syncing), this will also help writing to a disk.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what dvnrrs has said:
The sendfile is more efficient (though sendfile cannot be used always) because data copy doesn't happen to and from kernel to user space. Generally when we copy using read and write system call---- read copies data from kernel space to user space; and write copies data from user space to kernel space.

Comment: I'm guessing `cp` uses `sendfile()` itself, when possible, so I would expect the times to be identical; but I haven't actually tried it, or looked at the `cp` source code, or strace'd it. That's why I'm encouraging the OP to run his own benchmarks. But it certainly shouldn't be *slower* than `cp`.

Comment: cp cannot use sendfile. Becasue for sendfile, output file descriptor has to be a socket and input file descriptor has to be for mmap-able file

Comment: Only before kernel 2.6.33, at least for Linux, but I suppose you're probably right, unless there's a special case in the `cp` code.

Answer (score 0):

Sendfile is usually more efficient as others have pointed out. The best way to know the difference is to measure on your own machine.

The rule of thumb is use sendfile when you can. Don't try to be too smart when using sendfile though. I tried to use a buffer from mmapping a file (instead of malloc or mmap with MAP_ANONYMOUS) as scratch space for my processing, just so that I could call sendfile on the underlying FD instead of making write calls. It wasn't a good idea.

Comment: I had the same question and I patched 'cp' to use 'sendfile': https://github.com/0xdky/coreutils/commit/98fd0cba2b839cd2b77d57397998391a81baa55f